# How to copy another columns value to a new created value in SNOWFLAKE

Tags: datatable, copy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to add values to a newly created column from another column in SNOWFLAKE database, could someone please help.
I want values of OrderID column to be inserted in CompanyID

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table has to be updated:

```
UPDATE tab
SET CompanyID = OrderID
-- WHERE CompanyID IS NULL;
```

If the table is createad first time column CompanyID could be added inside CTAS:

```
CREATE TABLE tab
AS
SELECT OrderID AS CompanyID, OrderID, CustomerName
FROM db_soure_name.schema_name_table_name;
```